# grouping rows of common values to create a new 'group id' for each set

Tags: database, postgresql

I am trying to achieve the below but was not able to so far, any help would be greatly appreciated.
I have this data (sorted from a query by id, anchor, date, and time) that I wish to group by common anchor :

```
id anchor date        time     'group' (the value to get)
3  2      2019-01-01  07:00     1
4  2      2019-01-01  08:00     1
5  3      2019-01-01  15:00     2
7  3      2019-01-01  16:00     2
10 3      2019-01-01  17:00     2
```

I'm looking to do a query in postgres where I can select this data and foreach set of common anchors, have a 'group number'
I then need a query to sum the anchor of points of same group, example above would become:

```
anchor sum group
2      4   1
3      9   2
```

thanks!

EDIT: McNets solution works perfect,
I have another case, with below data.
The anchor repeats but after a change of anchor: they're sorted by time, first it was anchor 2, then anchor 3, then again anchor 2.
I need to group after the change (ids 11 & 12) to have a new group number in this case

```
id anchor date        time     'group' (the value to get)
3  2      2019-01-01  07:00     1
4  2      2019-01-01  08:00     1
5  3      2019-01-01  15:00     2
7  3      2019-01-01  16:00     2
10 3      2019-01-01  17:00     2
11 2      2019-01-01  18:00     3
12 2      2019-01-01  19:00     3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
SELECT
    anchor,
    SUM(anchor) AS sum,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY anchor) AS "group"
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    anchor;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: thanks! works perfect, another tricky case came up, I put it as an edit, would love to hear your thoughts